# Control Binding Times in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I want To know if there is a way to Define how many times a Grid can bind to a list ?

for example , If I have a list of 20 elements , can I restrict the Binding To just the First Ten elements of the list .

the problem is that I use the same list for 2 different controls , I need the first control to bind to the entire all list , and the second to bind to the first 10 elements .  so is there is anyway to do this from XAML ?

thanks :))

Comment: thisi is what ViewModel is for  isn't /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that case

```
public List<something> MyTopItems    
{
    get { return myItems.Take(10); }
}

public List<something> MyItems    
{
    get { return myItems; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your code-behind, or view-model, or wherever said list is, just set a property that exposes what you want:

```
public IEnumerable<something> MyTopElements
{
    get { return myList.Take(10); }
}
```

and bind to that instead

Comment: the problem is that I use the same list to bind to 2 different controls , I need the first control to bind to the entire all list , and the second to bind to the first 10 elements .

Comment: Your code won't compile. Either change the property type to `IEnumerable<something>` or call `myList.Take(10).ToList();`

Comment: @HajarIbrahiem Use two different view model properties?!

Comment: I solved it using different List source for each control . I just hoped that Xaml could solve the issue .